# Create new list from first row in a python list

Tags: python

I'm really new to python and need some help displaying the descriptive header in a list:

```
>>>y = [
    # First line is a descriptive header. 
    ['Beatle', 'Song 1', 'Song 2', 'Song 3'],
    ['George', '79', '90', '80'],
    ['Paul', '88', '82', '89']
]
```

I'm able to create a new list to separate out the data rows past the first (George & Paul) but need to show certain ranges in the first row (Example: Song 1 & Song 2).

```
##To return the beatles names in a list:
>>>def beatles(matrix, i):
    return [row[i] for row in matrix]
>>>beatles(y[1:2],0)
['George', 'Paul']


##To return the song number (header)
#Trying:
>>>songnumber = [i[1:2] for i in y]
>>>print(songnumber)
Returns:[['79'], ['90']]
```

Comment: Welcome! Whats your desired output?

Comment: I don't get it ? Do you want your output to be `['Beatle', 'George', 'Paul']` ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you would like to see as output?

Comment: This is an example of a larger set I'm working so it's simplistic for the post. Looking for [['Song1], [Song2]]

Answer (score 0):

Index into the array `y` such as `y[2][3]` has the value `'89'`

You could create a dictionary from each row then access the bits you want using names:

```
fields = y[0]
for row in y[1:]:
    d = dict(zip(fields, row))
    print d['Beatle'], d['Song 2']
```